# Why my ThreeJS model (OBJ) always renders black?

Tags: three.js

No matter how I change the materials i use, the model always renders black.However, when i use another model, it works normally.

current model

[image: current model IMG]

model works well

[image: old model IMG]

I use the same code to load and render both model, but the results are not same.

Another extra question:how can i upload my model here?

**WHAT I WANT TO DO**:

1. figure out the reason why it renders black.
2. make the model reflect light correctly.

thanks!!

Comment: in your .obj file does it have lines that start with `vn` like [this](https://github.com/gfxfundamentals/threejsfundamentals/blob/9333e4c83e0bb930b397d352881c97e21b14040e/threejs/resources/models/windmill/windmill.obj#L798)? If not the file is missing normals. You either need to re-export with normals or if you can't re-export then you can ask three.js to generate them by calling geometry.computeVertexNormals().

Comment: you are totally right!! I open the .obj file and found there is no any line start with `vn`. So i use FBX file instead and then it works, thank you very much!